# How to create a translate function that accepts string and dictionary and returns a string which is the translation of the original string?

Tags: python, function, dictionary

I’ve supplied an example string and dictionary the returned string would be “dia duit python mic leinn ta focloiri is spraiuil”. If the word isn’t in the dictionary return the original word. How do i translate the string by using the englishGaelic dictionary?

```
string='hello python students dictionaries are fun'
englishGaelic={'hello':'dia duit','python':'python','students':'mic leinn','dictionaries':'ta focloiri','are':'is','fun':'spraiuil'}
```

I've tried to write down some code but couldn't really figure out how to replace the string with the given dictionary. Best i could do is this, but the output remains the same.

```
def translate(txt,dictionary):
    for i in txt:
        if i not in dictionary:
            return txt
        else:
            convert = ' '.join([dictionary.get(p,p) for p in txt.split(' ')])
    print(convert)

string='hello python students dictionaries are fun'
englishGaelic={'hello':'dia duit','python':'python','students':'mic leinn','dictionaries':'ta focloiri','are':'is','fun':'spraiuil'}

print(translate(string,englishGaelic))
```

Comment: For starters, `for i in txt:` loops over the *characters* of the message, not the *words*.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your attempt:

- This loops over characters in a string, not words (and keep in mind, that non-printable characters are also included):

```
for i in txt:
# If txt="A b"
# this loop will yield "A", " ", "b"
```

- you cannot `return` in the `for` loop, you have to aggregate the results in some data structure (e.g. a `list`) otherwise even if you loop over words and not characters you will get a single (first in fact) word only
- python likes sneak_case, use it

Solution:

- loop over words
- get translated word or use original if it's not in the mapping
- aggregate the results
- join the results to a single string

```py
def translate(txt: str,dictionary: dict)->str:
    """
    Translate text using mapping. 
    If a word is absent return original one.
    """
    translated_words = []
    words = txt.split(" ")
    for word in words:
        translated_words.append(dictionary.get(word, word))
    return ' '.join(translated_words)
    # Alternatively the one-liner below does the same
    # return ' '.join([dictionary.get(word, word) for word in txt.split(" ")])


string='hello python students dictionaries are fun'
english_gaelic={'hello':'dia duit','python':'python','students':'mic leinn','dictionaries':'ta focloiri','are':'is','fun':'spraiuil'}

print(translate(string,english_gaelic))
```

Comment: instead of `translated_word = dictionary.get(word) if dictionary.get(word) is not None else word` ... just use `        translated_word = dictionary.get(word, word)`. The get() method has a default param.